# 3TB Airport Time Capsule (FW 7.7.3) Incorrect DNS address delivered by DHCP

Tags: network, airport, time-capsule, dns

3TB Airport Time Capsule (FW 7.7.3) DHCP sends the correct DNS address to hosts for the Primary network, but sends the Gateway address for the Guest network.  If I correct the DNS manually on a host, Internet works fine.  What's the problem?

Any LAN Host:
DNS 172.16.42.1
Should be 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 1):

I got this hint from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2735366?start=0&tstart=0

Check out the last post from Paul Verity.

> I've just hit on this problem too, and also found that deleting the
>   DNS entries in my TimeCapsules DNS configuration fixed the problem.

Comment: Interesting... I'll give it a try.  My current TC 1st DNS entry is my Windows Server AD DNS for my private domain and the 2nd is Googles 8.8.8.8.  When I go back to look at the TC settings its applied an IPv6 entry as well??

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/27159746